# An issue with Drawing an Image - Android

Tags: java, android, image

I have followed a few tutorials and the next logical step in learning Android is a simple ability to draw an image. However, there are some issues I am having.

I am currently using the following class to draw my image:

```
public class GameSetup extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView ARImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    ARImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ship1);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    WindowManager windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
    int displayHeight = display.getHeight();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ARImage.setLayoutParams(position);
    position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    layout.addView(ARImage, position);
    setContentView(layout);
  }
}
```

1. Is this the most appropriate way for me to do this? It *does* work, however I am fairly certain there are simpler ways of doing this (though I may be mistaken)
2. How do I call this from another class? Googling yeilded me the possibility of something along the lines of this to call an Activity from a separate class, but I am unsure of how exactly to word this:

   ```
   GameSetup gameSetup = new GameSetup(MyActivity.this);
   gameSetup.onCreate();
   ```

I am unsure of what "MyActivity" should refer to. I have tried several variables there, including "MainActivity", which eclipse thinks is correct, but whatever I try just doesn't seem to work as it should.

Comment: Are you deliberately writing it in code? Typically in Android development you use XML files to define your layout.

Comment: Oh? I have only done programming before in c++ and base java, I wasn't aware of this. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a link to the Android development guidelines on this topic, hopefully should get you started

Answer (score 1):

1: NO, it's easier to make an xml layout containing all your elements.

i.e.:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ARImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/R.drawable.ship1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you assign this layout in your onCreateView, through setContentView.

i.e.:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make this activity, full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.game_setup);
}
```

2: You start another activity by using an intent

i.e.:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameSetup.class));
```

Comment: great, thanks. I am going to attempt this code right here. For calling this, what is wrong with this code:

 @startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameSetup.class))@

 gameSetup.onCreate();


Eclipse tells me I need the "@"'s around the former line. (sorry I don't know how to format comments well)

Comment: This sounds very strange. just comment out your onCreate and insert mine (after you put your xml layout in res/layout). Maybe, you are calling this **startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameSetup.class))** inside GameSetup? it would result in an infinite loop...

Comment: hm, I am getting this: http://i.imgur.com/Gb354Lt.png

I am also getting the same at the end and upon removing my function call, I am getting issues with Intent

Comment: Is GameSetup Activity defined? Do you have the correct imports at the top of your Class? You need **AT LEAST** these imports: `import android.app.Activity;`, `import android.content.Context;`, `import android.content.Intent;`, `import android.os.Build;`, `import android.os.Bundle;`... It seems to me that you are trying to write the code all manually? that's an overkill!!

Comment: ah, seems I was missing my Import and Build imports, thanks!

However, I am still having the same issues with my startactivity line... I have only ever learned how to code this stuff manually, just trying to get my mind around this new method now! :P (there is a surprising lack of tutorials on basic image drawing online)

Comment: Well, wouldn't it be easier if you do... File/New/Class? Anyway, make sure you also have the packege declaration as the very first line in your class: something like: `package com.example.android.a_game;` Then must go the imports. Then the Class itself. In your MainActivivty you will call the startActivity command (presumably in a menu item click or at the click of a button).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is detailed in the [Android documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)